# I can't run the ![alt text](img.png) markdown code in my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, image, kernel, jupyter, command-prompt

This is the error popping up:
'[]' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[[image: Error image]

Answer (score 2):

You didn't change the cell type from "code" to "markdown", so everything after the `!` is interpreted as a terminal/CLI command.

[image]